# Jboss service won't start

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gwt, jboss, persistence

I'm developing a GWT application in Eclipse on JBoss AS7. However, when I try to deploy, I get this

```
13:11:52,546 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."ctivTools_GWT.war#Catalog": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."ctivTools_GWT.war#Catalog": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/C:/Users/mettens/Documents/Startproject%20GWT/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ctivTools_GWT.war/WEB-INF/classes/
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011431: Could not load entity class 'be.vito.ctivtools.client.generic.GwtRpcDataSource' with PersistenceUnitInfo.getClassLoader()
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: be.vito.ctivtools.client.generic.GwtRpcDataSource from [Module "deployment.ctivTools_GWT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
```

The Hibernate service won't start apparently. I have no idea why. I tried adding more libraries, facets and classes, but with no effect.
I compile my application to a WAR File and deploy it afterwards.

Comment: It's right there: `ClassNotFoundException: be.vito.ctivtools.client.generic.GwtRpcDataSource ...` - we really can't help you without knowing your build procedure and artifact content...

Comment: And how would I post my build procedure and artifact content?

Comment: Well I'm sorry, Sir, since I didn't know which details about my project to post, I figured it'd be better to let the community ask me questions.

Comment: What he's saying is that you should start with the error message - you shouldn't have "no idea why" it isn't starting. The class `be.vito.ctivtools.client.generic.GwtRpcDataSource` is missing from the server classpath - is that part of your project (and so should be in WEB-INF/classes/`)? Is it part of a library (and so should be in `WEB-INF/lib/`)? In short, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for be.vito.ctivtools.client.generic.GwtRpcDataSource in your code base.

Identify which binary ( jars ) it should be included in. Ensure that jar is in your WEB-INF/lib.

If you are not building any jars ensure  GwtRpcDataSource.class file is in WEB-INF/classes/be/vito/ctivtools/client/generic folder .