# Security filter in JAX-RS causes errors

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS based application and want access to certain services be restricted according to the @RolesAllowed annotation. To achieve that I created a filter, but it seems there is some problem with configuration. JBoss can't find ContainerRequestFilter (interface , which is part of JAX-RS specification and is implemented - as far as I know - in RestEasy 3.x (I'm using 3.0.4.Final). The second problem is that SecurityFilter, from what I undestood, class is treated as an JPA entity, even though it's not annotated with @Entity. I have already seen this problem posted somewhere on the Internet, but it remained without answer. When filter class is not included the project works just fine.

Here are the messages:

```
19:32:41,792 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define class com.xxx.xx.xxx.SecurityFilter in Module "deployment.WorkersManager.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/xxx/xx/xxx/SecurityFilter (Module "deployment.WorkersManager.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter from [Module "deployment.WorkersManager.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
... 25 more
19:32:41,855 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."WorkersManager.war#WorkersManager": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."WorkersManager.war#WorkersManager": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/home/xxx/JBoss/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/WorkersManager.war/WEB-INF/classes/
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011431: Could not load entity class 'com.xxx.xx.xxx.SecurityFilter' with PersistenceUnitInfo.getClassLoader()
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:175)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.SecurityFilter from [Module "deployment.WorkersManager.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Sounds like a classic classpath issue.  Make sure that the jarFile that contains  `javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter` is loaded in WEB-INF/lib directory of your binary.

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293835/jboss-service-wont-start

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependencies into you `pom.xml`. There is a missing dependecy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you aren't adding this class as a provided dependency:

Your log says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/home/xxx/JBoss/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/WorkersManager.war/WEB-INF/classes/
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
```

could you open your generated war and look for the jar file that should contain it? In case it wasn't there you should provide the required .jar with the .war file (in case you were building the war with maven you should modify the pom.xml to provide the .jar )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this helped:

project properties -> Deployment Assembly -> add -> build path entries -> maven dependencies

It seems that even though dependecies were added to pom.xml (and I ran maven build after that), they were not included in the deployment.